# Inno Setup [Setup] 64bit conditional

Tags: inno-setup

In the `[Setup]` section of Inno Setup can I conditionally define `AppId` and `AppMutex` based on whether the system is 64bit or not?

Reason being is I have two separate installers at the moment for 32 and 64bit but I want to create just one combined installer but dont want to mess up the currently deployed versions by having new AppId's and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants):

```
[Setup]
AppId={code:GetAppId}
; UsePreviousLanguage must be set to "no" when AppId includes constants.
UsePreviousLanguage=no
```

```pascal
[Code]

function GetAppId(Param: string): string;
begin
  if IsWin64 then Result := 'myapp64'
    else Result := 'myapp32';
end;
```